# C言語での2次元配列の最大値と最小値

Tags: c

以下の問題に対して、二重ループを使った最大値と最小値の求め方が分かりません。
どのようにして２つのループを使い求めれば良いのでしょうか。

> **問題:**
>
> 以下の配列から1列の最大値と最小値、2列の最大値と最小値を二重ループを使い求める。
> この時、1列の最大値は `max[0]`に、最小値は `min[0]` 、2列の最大値は `max[1]` に、最小値は `min[1]` に格納する。

```
x[4][2]={{3,2},
         {2,5},
         {5,2},
         {4,1}};
```

Comment: 1次元であれば求められますか？

Comment: 求められません。二重ループになると一次元でも分からなくなります。

Comment: 1つのループなら使えますか？という意味で聞きました。例えば{3, 1, 2}から最大値を求められますか？

Comment: 列(2次元目)のループを外側に、行(1次元目)のループを内側にすれば出来るでしょう。

Comment: 何よりもまず、C++タグを付けておきながらタイトルにC言語と書く矛盾に気づいてください。C言語とC++言語はインドとインドネシアぐらい違います。

Comment: @merino１つのループならif文を使い求めることができました。

Comment: @kunif それも試したのですが列を分けることが出来ませんでした。

Comment: @Sayuri そうなんですか！？c言語の参考書を使いVisual StudioでVisual c++を使っているのですが、これはc言語で合っていますか？合っている場合cタグにすれば良いでしょうか。

Comment: まずは" 言葉による説明" でやるべき手続きを書き出してみる、もしくはフローチャートを作成したり、問題を単純化 = いったん2列目は脇に置いて1列目のみを対象に最大値(最小値)を求めてみる…などを試してみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: 課題の類なら、自分でやらないと何も身に付きませんよ。

Comment: @cubick フローチャート、単純化ですか。まだまだ分からない問題があるので試してみます！

Comment: @radian ですよね。わかってます。すみません。フローチャートなど使ってプログラミングの考え方を変えて頑張ります。

Comment: デバッグで一行ずつステップ実行したり、変化してく変数の中身を見る事で、動作を理解しやすくなります。何はともあれ、とりあえず動かしてみることです。 https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

Comment: @radian 地道にやることが大事なんですね。そのサイトを参考に頑張ってみます。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「１つのループならif文を使い求めることができました。」とか「それも試したのですが列を分けることが出来ませんでした。」あたりの試行錯誤の状況や、その時のソースコードも質問に追記すると貴方の理解度が明確化されて、考え方/着目点への助言が出やすいでしょう。

それで私のコメント「列(2次元目)のループを外側に、行(1次元目)のループを内側にすれば出来るでしょう。」に沿った内容としては以下のように出来るはずです。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int max[2] = { INT_MIN,INT_MIN };
    int min[2] = { INT_MAX,INT_MAX };
    int x[4][2] = { {3,2},
                    {2,5},
                    {5,2},
                    {4,1} };

    for (int column = 0; column < 2; column++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            int n = x[row][column];

            if (max[column] < n) {
                max[column] = n;
            }
            if (min[column] > n) {
                min[column] = n;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("最大値：1列目=%d, 2列目=%d\n", max[0], max[1]);
    printf("最小値：1列目=%d, 2列目=%d\n", min[0], min[1]);
}
```